# Create a Container Div with DOM/XPATH

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I just created a new DOM XPATH OBJECT.

And, after a couple operations I've storage my result with `SaveHtml`

```
$String[] = $dom->saveHTML();
```

And then, Ive just put the content inside a file.

```
file_put_contents($filename, $string);
```

The Html Structure is someting like this.

```
  <div if="rand11">
  </div>
  <div if="rand24">
  </div>
  <div if="rand51">
  </div>
```

There is some methods in order to create new divs. You can use `->createElement`. Also, you can place this new element with `->parentNode->insertBefore` but its no possible to create a container div, like this.

```
  <div if="container-div">
  <div if="rand11">
  </div>
  <div if="rand24">
  </div>
  <div if="rand51">
  </div> </div>
```

I tried multiples ways to do it without success.

So, I have a couple questions:

**1. It is possible to create a Container Div modifying the Dom directly?**

**2. It is possible to adding a new Html element of an Array that contains `$dom->saveHTML();` data?**

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is. Most of it is actually uses the same methods. For example `appendChild()/insertBefore()` are not just used for new nodes, they can move existing nodes.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div if="rand11"></div>
<div if="rand24"></div>
<div if="rand51"></div>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// fetch the nodes that should be put inside the container
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//div[starts-with(@if, "rand")]');
// validate that here is at least one node
if ($first = $nodes[0]) {
    // create the container and insert it before the first
    $container = $first->parentNode->insertBefore(
        $document->createElement('div'), $first
    );
    $container->setAttribute('class', 'container-div');
    // move all the fetched nodes into the container
    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        $container->appendChild($node);
    }

    // output formatted
    $document->formatOutput = TRUE;
    echo $document->saveHTML($container);
}
```

Output:

```
<div class="container-div"> 
<div if="rand11"></div> 
<div if="rand24"></div> 
<div if="rand51"></div> 
</div>
```